# Bone heat weighting error when Rigging model

Tags: modeling, rigging, rigify, pose-mode

Ok, so I've basically never used Blender before and it's been so long since I used a 3d modeling program I can be considered completely new. I'm attempting to rig a model but I get this Bone Heat Weighting error on the last step and I have no clue why it's happenening or how to fix it. Part of me things that the gun that was included along side the model in the .obj file is responsible but not only am I not sure, I don't know how to properly get rid of it (or easily). Can anyone correct/help this poor noob?

[image]

here is a link to the original model https://cults3d.com/en/3d-model/art/community-guardsmen-project-hub (look for the steel legion trooper)

and here's the tutorial I originally followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHa2Y8zjtZQ&list=WL&index=1&t=395s. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Rather than sending people off to hunt down tutorials and models, it would be better if you added your blend file to your question. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))
Normally that error means one of three things, you have duplicate vertices, intersecting meshes, or a mesh that's just too complicated; but it's impossible to tell without the actual blend file.

Comment: This model is one object but has over 1000 loose parts. I recommend the "The Duplicate, Remesh, and Transfer Method" in the linked question above.

Comment: So, the method from the linked question did not work. I sent a message to the model maker and asked how they got it to pose and see if they get back to me any time soon. I'll come back and post the solution as best I can if that happens. Thanks for the help.